# C# Windows forms - want to update text box value dynamically

Tags: winforms

I have two forms - with multiple text boxes (both look the same)

If I change the value of tb1 on form1, tb1 on form2 should be updated on the fly without having to open the form2 again and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Form1 opens Form2.

In Form2, create a Public Property to expose the TextBox to other Classes:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{

    public TextBox TB2
    {
        get
        {
            return this.tb2;
        }
    }

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

}
```

In Form1, now you can use the public property to access the TextBox in Form2:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private Form2 f2 = null;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (f2 == null || f2.IsDisposed)
        {
            f2 = new Form2();
            f2.TB2.Text = this.tb1.Text;
            f2.Show();
        }
    }

    private void tb1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (f2 != null && !f2.IsDisposed)
        {
            f2.TB2.Text = this.tb1.Text;
        }
    }

}
```

Note the "f2" field that tracks whether we have an instance of Form2 open already.